# getrowclass inside initcomponent does not work

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have code like below

```
initComponent: function()
    {       
        var me = this;
        this.callParent(arguments);

        var rowAlerterCond = this.rowAlerter;
        if(rowAlerterCond !== undefined && rowAlerterCond !==null && typeof rowAlerterCond ==='object')
        {
            var returnVar = this.buildCondition(rowAlerterCond);
            this.rowHighlightConfig = returnVar;
           me.viewConfig.getRowClass = function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {      
            if(this.rowHighlightConfig)
               return eval(this.rowHighlightConfig) ? 'orangeHighlight' : '';
         };
        }
    },
```

here getRowClass never gets invoked. Should i change anything? If i add getRowClass inside of viewConfig it works, but i need to traverse up the tree to get the rowHighlightConfig variable. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The `viewConfig` is used to, well, configure the View class used by the grid panel. This View is instantiated and configured in the parent `initComponent` - the one you invoke at line 4.

After that, it's too late to modify the viewConfig, as the view is made. So you need to set up the viewConfig *before* invoking `callParent`.

How do you do that? Well, the beautiful thing about the `getRowClass` property is that it takes a function - or a closure. So something *like* this:

```js
initComponent: function() {       
  var me = this; // important to grab this; the getRowClass will run in a different scope

  this.viewConfig = this.viewConfig || {}
  this.viewConfig.getRowClass = function() {
    if (!Ext.isDefined(me.rowHighlightConfig) {
      var rowAlerterCond = me.rowAlerter;
      if (Ext.isObject(rowAlerterCond) {
        var returnVar = me.buildCondition(rowAlerterCond);
        me.rowHighlightConfig = returnVar;
      } else {
        me.rowHighlightConfig = 'orangeHighlight'
     }
     return eval(me.rowHighlightConfig);
   }

   this.callParent(arguments); // Now call the parent initComponent
}
```